# Xorg wrong color display

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux, framebuffer, xorg

I've installed Xorg on a HDMI stick with fbdev driver,
everything work ( mouse and keyboard ) but the color are really strange,
i put you the photo of the aspect of google for example :
[Rendering of google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqy5t.jpg)

Here is my Xorg log :

```
[    14.976] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[    14.976] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    14.976] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-4-armmp-lpae armv7l Debian
[    14.976] Current Operating System: Linux (none) 3.18.24 #3 SMP Thu Mar 1 21:21:09 CET 2018 armv7l
[    14.977] Build Date: 16 October 2017  09:26:27AM
[    14.977] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1+deb8u2 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[    14.977] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    14.977]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    14.977] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    14.978] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jan  1 00:00:14 1970
[    14.985] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    14.988] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    14.988] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    14.988] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    14.988] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    14.990] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    14.990] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "off"
[    14.990] (**) Not automatically adding devices
[    14.990] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    14.991] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    14.998] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    14.998]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.002] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    15.002] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    15.002] (==) |-->Input Device "<default pointer>"
[    15.002] (==) |-->Input Device "<default keyboard>"
[    15.002] (==) No Layout section. Using the default mouse configuration.
[    15.003] (==) No Layout section. Using the default keyboard configuration.
[    15.003] (II) Loader magic: 0xb6ef4f20
[    15.003] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    15.003]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    15.003]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[    15.003]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    15.003]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    15.004] (II) no primary bus or device found
[    15.004] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    15.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    15.059] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.059]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    15.059]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[    15.059] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    15.059] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[    15.059] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[    15.059] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    15.059] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.064] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module modesetting
[    15.064] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.064] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    15.064] (EE) Failed to load module "modesetting" (module does not exist, 0)
[    15.065] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    15.065] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    15.066] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.066]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 0.4.4
[    15.066]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.066]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.066] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
[    15.067] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
[    15.069] (II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.069]    compiled for 1.16.1, module version = 1.9.1
[    15.069]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    15.069]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    15.069] (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
[    15.070] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/kbd_drv.so
[    15.071] (II) Module kbd: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.071]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 1.8.0
[    15.071]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    15.071]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    15.071] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    15.072] (--) using VT number 2

[    15.072] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[    15.073] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    15.073] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    15.073] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    15.075] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    15.076] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.076]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    15.077]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.216] (II) FBDEV(0): using default device
[    15.298] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    15.298] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    15.298] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    15.298] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    15.298] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    15.298] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: hifb (video memory: 16200kB)
[    15.298] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    15.298] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    15.299] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1920x1080 (pitch 1920)
[    15.299] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current"
[    15.299] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    15.299] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    15.299] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    15.299] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    15.302] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.302]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    15.302]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    15.302] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    15.303] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    15.303] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    15.304] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    15.305] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.305]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.1.0
[    15.305]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    15.306] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    15.307] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[    15.310] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    15.312] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    15.313] (==) RandR enabled
[    15.388] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    15.398] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    15.398] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    15.457] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    15.457] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[    15.851] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for '<default pointer>'
[    15.851] (**) Option "CorePointer" "on"
[    15.852] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[    15.852] (WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...
[    15.873] (II) <default pointer>: Setting Device option to "/dev/input/mice"
[    15.873] (--) <default pointer>: Device: "/dev/input/mice"
[    15.873] (==) <default pointer>: Protocol: "Auto"
[    15.873] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[    15.873] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
[    15.898] (==) <default pointer>: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
[    15.898] (**) <default pointer>: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    15.898] (**) <default pointer>: Buttons: 9
[    15.898] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "<default pointer>" (type: MOUSE, id 6)
[    15.899] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    15.899] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    15.899] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    15.899] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    15.899] (II) <default pointer>: Setting mouse protocol to "ExplorerPS/2"
[    16.192] (II) <default pointer>: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
[    16.192] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for '<default keyboard>'
[    16.192] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard" "on"
[    16.192] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[    16.193] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[    16.193] (**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
[    16.193] (**) Option "XkbRules" "base"
[    16.193] (**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
[    16.193] (**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
[    16.193] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "<default keyboard>" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    16.226] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   616.310] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   616.310] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   616.320] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1121.162] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1276.718] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[  1276.719] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[  1276.744] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1276.747] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  1276.748] (==) RandR enabled
[  1276.824] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1276.833] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  1276.833] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[  1276.841] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  1276.841] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  1277.149] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for '<default pointer>'
[  1277.149] (**) Option "CorePointer" "on"
[  1277.149] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  1277.149] (WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...
[  1277.170] (II) <default pointer>: Setting Device option to "/dev/input/mice"
[  1277.170] (--) <default pointer>: Device: "/dev/input/mice"
[  1277.170] (==) <default pointer>: Protocol: "Auto"
[  1277.170] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  1277.170] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
[  1277.195] (==) <default pointer>: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
[  1277.195] (**) <default pointer>: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  1277.195] (**) <default pointer>: Buttons: 9
[  1277.195] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1277.195] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  1277.195] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1277.195] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1277.195] (II) <default pointer>: Setting mouse protocol to "ExplorerPS/2"
[  1277.487] (II) <default pointer>: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
[  1277.487] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for '<default keyboard>'
[  1277.487] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard" "on"
[  1277.487] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  1277.488] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  1277.488] (**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
[  1277.488] (**) Option "XkbRules" "base"
[  1277.488] (**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
[  1277.488] (**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
[  1277.722] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1408.209] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[  1408.210] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[  1408.231] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1408.234] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  1408.234] (==) RandR enabled
[  1408.310] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1408.320] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  1408.320] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[  1408.328] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  1408.328] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  1408.648] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for '<default pointer>'
[  1408.648] (**) Option "CorePointer" "on"
[  1408.649] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  1408.649] (WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...
[  1408.668] (II) <default pointer>: Setting Device option to "/dev/input/mice"
[  1408.668] (--) <default pointer>: Device: "/dev/input/mice"
[  1408.668] (==) <default pointer>: Protocol: "Auto"
[  1408.668] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  1408.668] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
[  1408.690] (==) <default pointer>: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
[  1408.690] (**) <default pointer>: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  1408.690] (**) <default pointer>: Buttons: 9
[  1408.690] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1408.690] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  1408.690] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1408.690] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1408.690] (II) <default pointer>: Setting mouse protocol to "ExplorerPS/2"
[  1408.983] (II) <default pointer>: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
[  1408.983] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for '<default keyboard>'
[  1408.983] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard" "on"
[  1408.983] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  1408.983] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  1408.983] (**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
[  1408.983] (**) Option "XkbRules" "base"
[  1408.984] (**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
[  1408.984] (**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
[  1409.218] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1474.113] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[  1474.113] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[  1474.135] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  1474.137] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  1474.138] (==) RandR enabled
[  1474.215] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1474.224] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  1474.225] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[  1474.233] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  1474.233] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  1474.521] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for '<default pointer>'
[  1474.522] (**) Option "CorePointer" "on"
[  1474.522] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  1474.522] (WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...
[  1474.540] (II) <default pointer>: Setting Device option to "/dev/input/mice"
[  1474.540] (--) <default pointer>: Device: "/dev/input/mice"
[  1474.540] (==) <default pointer>: Protocol: "Auto"
[  1474.540] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  1474.540] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
[  1474.559] (==) <default pointer>: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
[  1474.559] (**) <default pointer>: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  1474.559] (**) <default pointer>: Buttons: 9
[  1474.559] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1474.559] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  1474.559] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1474.559] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1474.559] (II) <default pointer>: Setting mouse protocol to "ExplorerPS/2"
[  1474.851] (II) <default pointer>: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
[  1474.851] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for '<default keyboard>'
[  1474.851] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard" "on"
[  1474.851] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  1474.852] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  1474.852] (**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
[  1474.852] (**) Option "XkbRules" "base"
[  1474.852] (**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
[  1474.852] (**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
[  1475.087] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  2034.772] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[  2034.772] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[  2034.794] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  2034.797] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  2034.797] (==) RandR enabled
[  2034.873] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  2034.883] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  2034.883] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[  2034.891] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  2034.891] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  2035.196] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for '<default pointer>'
[  2035.196] (**) Option "CorePointer" "on"
[  2035.197] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  2035.197] (WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...
[  2035.221] (II) <default pointer>: Setting Device option to "/dev/input/mice"
[  2035.221] (--) <default pointer>: Device: "/dev/input/mice"
[  2035.221] (==) <default pointer>: Protocol: "Auto"
[  2035.221] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events
[  2035.221] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
[  2035.243] (==) <default pointer>: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50
[  2035.243] (**) <default pointer>: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  2035.243] (**) <default pointer>: Buttons: 9
[  2035.243] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  2035.243] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  2035.243] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  2035.243] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  2035.243] (II) <default pointer>: Setting mouse protocol to "ExplorerPS/2"
[  2035.535] (II) <default pointer>: ps2EnableDataReporting: succeeded
[  2035.535] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for '<default keyboard>'
[  2035.535] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard" "on"
[  2035.535] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  2035.535] (**) <default keyboard>: always reports core events
[  2035.535] (**) Option "Protocol" "standard"
[  2035.536] (**) Option "XkbRules" "base"
[  2035.536] (**) Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
[  2035.536] (**) Option "XkbLayout" "us"
[  2035.770] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
```

And every applications have this problems of colors,
if you need more information tell me,
I hope you can help me,
Nikoala

Comment: It is on a TV or on a screen? Could you test on other devices? I suspect a mismatch of format expectation between the driver and the screen. Some screens do not support all format (especially from computers, so full size, full RGB range)..

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, so I have tested on a TV 720p ,UHD TV and computer monitor, I have the exactly same problem,  It seems to concern only the white and grey who appear in black, other colors appears correctly .

Comment: I do not understand. "I have the exactly same problem" which is different to "other colors appears correctly". I would check in one of such screens, it I can get which signal I get (something like RGB, YCC, 4:2:2, and e.v. colour space). Then I'll try to configure your hardware, so that it will use the expected output format in HDMI

Comment: You may also check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Weathered_colors_.28color_range_problem.29

Comment: Thank for your time @giacomo-catenazzi , I have the exactly same problem on every screen but the problem seems to concern only white and grey, sorry if I was not clear, i have tried your link but it seems to concerns only Intel graphics and I didn't use them ( I use framebuffer with fbdev drivers), on my screen I tried RGB and YPbPr, with RGB i have problem with white grey, With YPbPr I still have problem and every color are mad. 
I add you a photo where you can see the problem :  https://imgur.com/a/l5tHMS3

Comment: The problem it is the same, just how to tell your hardware to use the correct RGB range (there are two ranges: usual television 16-235 and usual computer (and web) 0-255 per channel (R, G, B). `fddev` is just an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, I change the color depth at the launch of Xorg with :

```
/usr/bin/X -depth 16 &
```

Thank you for your time !